# Get tag tree in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Earlier versions of drupal had the `taxonomy_get_tree` function, but that has been removed.

Now I can load the vocabulary by doing:

```
$vocabulary = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Vocabulary::load('applications');
```

But I can't find any useful information about how to get all the tags in a vocabulary.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Have you figured this out? Same issue here ...

Answer (score 0):

$termsTree = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree('tags');

Provides terms of the specified vocabulary.

Comment: Please, extend your answer and include as to why OP should choose this as solution.